# How to Sync PHP and NodeJS with Redis and get data in order

Tags: php, node.js, redis

I have a example code for make experiments trying to think "how to ""sync"" nodejs and php in a simple chat example.

Here is my NodeJS server:

```
var redis       = require('redis'),
    subscriber  = redis.createClient(),
    publisher   = redis.createClient();

//var sckio = require('socket.io').listen(8888);
var http = require('http');
var querystring = require('querystring');

var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server

var ENCODING = 'utf8';

var tCounter = 0;

/* #################################### */

// Event on "subscribe" to any channel
subscriber.on("subscribe", function (channel, count) {

    // Publish to redis server Test Message
    publisher.publish("chat", "NODEJS MESSAGE");

});

// Suscrib to redis server
subscriber.on('message', function (channel, json) {
    console.log('SUB: ' + channel + ' | ' + json);

    console.log('PHP PUSH TO REDIS, AND NODE CAPTURE REDIS PUSH: ' + (getMicrotime(true) - tCounter));       

});

subscriber.subscribe('chat'); // Subs to "mysql" channel


/*
var clients = [];
sckio.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

  clients.push(socket);
  publisher.publish("chat", "User connected");

  socket.on('message', function (from, msg) {

    publisher.publish("chat", msg);

    clients.forEach(function (client) {
      if (client === socket) return;
      client.send(msg);
    });

  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function () {

    clients.splice(clients.indexOf(socket), 1);
    publisher.publish("chat", "User disconnected");

  });

});
*/

var wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 8888, timeout : 500});
var wsClients = [];

wss.on('connection', function(ws) {


    ws.AUTH_ID = Math.random();
    wsClients.push(ws);

    publisher.publish("chat", "User enter");

    ws.on('message', function(message) {

        wsClients.forEach(function (client) {
           client.send(ws.AUTH_ID + ' ' + message);
        });

        tCounter = getMicrotime(true);
        console.log('CALL TO PHP: ' + tCounter);

        PostCode('CODE TO PHP FROM NODE', function() {
            wsClients.forEach(function (client) {
               client.send('PHP SAVE DATA');
            });

        });

    });

    ws.on('close', function(message) {

      wsClients.splice(wsClients.indexOf(ws), 1);
      publisher.publish("chat", "User left");

    });

    ws.send('HELLO USER!');

});    

function getMicrotime(get_as_float) {
    var now = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
    var s = parseInt(now, 10);

    return (get_as_float) ? now : (Math.round((now - s) * 1000) / 1000) + ' ' + s;
}

function PostCode(codestring, callback) {

  // Build the post string from an object
  var post_data = querystring.stringify({
      'output_format': 'json',
        'js_code' : codestring
  });

  // An object of options to indicate where to post to
  var post_options = {
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      port: '80',
      path: '/NodeJS/chat_system/php_system.php',
      method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Content-Length': post_data.length
        }
  };

  // Set up the request
  var post_req = http.request(post_options, function(res) {
      res.setEncoding(ENCODING);
      res.on('data', function (chunk) {

          console.log('Response FROM PHP: ' + chunk);
          if (typeof callback == 'function') {
            callback(chunk);
          }

      });
  });

  // post the data
  post_req.write(post_data);
  post_req.end();

}
```

Here is my PHP Server

```
require 'Predis/Autoloader.php';
Predis\Autoloader::register();



function pushToRedis($data) {

    try {

        $redis = new Predis\Client(array(
            'scheme' => 'tcp',
            'host'   => '127.0.0.1',
            'port'   => 6379,
        ));       

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Couldn't connected to Redis";
        echo $e->getMessage();
        return false;
    }

    $json = json_encode($data);
    $redis->publish("chat", $json);

    return true;

}


pushToRedis('PHP PUSH TO REDIS!');

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('response' => print_r(array($_REQUEST, $_SERVER), true)));
```

And my client:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>WebSockets - Simple chat</title>

<style>

    .chat { width: 400px; height: 250px; overflow-y: scroll; }

</style>

</head>
<body>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<script>

    var connection = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8888');

    $(document).ready(function() {

        /*
        var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8888');
        socket.on('message', function (data) {
          alert(data);
        });
        socket.send('HELLO!');
        */


        connection.onopen = function () {
            console.log('connected!');
        };

        connection.onerror = function (error) {

        };  

        connection.onmessage = function (message) {
            $('.chat').append(message.data + '<br>');
            $('.chat').scrollTop($('.chat')[0].scrollHeight);
        };

        $('input[name="text"]').on('keydown', function(e) {

            if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                var msg = $(this).val();
                connection.send(msg);
                $(this).val('').focus();
            }

        });




    });


</script>


<div class="chat">

</div>

<input type="text" name="text">

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is the order of the PHP return the response to NodeJS via Redis when the network its bussy.

For example: I send more messages from de javascript client, then, NodeJS call to PHP every message, PHP save the data in MYSQL, and call Redis, NodeJS detect the Redis push and update the clients. But, in some cases, if i send from the Javascript client in loop some messages ( for(0-10000)) I dont reply to others clients in the same order, in cases geting numbers like 200,201,300,202,320,203 in the clients.

I think this is for the PHP delay to response.

My question is How i can manage the responses to update the clients, in the correct order? because this problem can cause, to clients receive the chat messages in wrong order.

Comment: I think you cant control this since you have 3 variables to account for, 1 the latency from node to php, 2 the latency of sql write, 3 latency of redis. i think... but im no expert.

Comment: I thinking in other way.. when i send from web-client to node, im wait to send to others users of the chatroom the message, and when it complete, send an "ok" to the original user to load the message in the message chat, this method "sync" the messages, but if the user have too latency, the message dont appear and user can think its not sended and try to write more.. "bad user experience" i think..
Wait for response is an option, but double the latency for the user..

Answer (score -3):

But why you want to use php you able to send data to mysql directly using mysql package of nodejs

You may install mysql package via :
npm install mysql

Connection made by :
mysql = require('mysql'),

connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'database name',
    port: 3306
  }),

And throw query by using :

var q=connection.query('select * from table);